# Defined proto enum types cannot generate corresponding enum classes after compilation [python]

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc-python, proto3

I have defined two enums in `common.proto` as follows：

```
syntax = "proto3";

package common;

message ClientTypeEnum {
  enum ClientType {
    SMB = 0;
    BV_VL = 1;
  }
};

enum ErrCode{
  PayCenterErrorCode_SUCCESS                      = 0;
  PayCenterErrorCode_REQ_PARAMS_ERROR             = 1000000;
  PayCenterErrorCode__ERROR                       = 1000001;
  PayCenterErrorCode__UNKNOWN_ERROR               = 1000002;
  PayCenterErrorCode__ACCOUNT_NOT_EXIST           = 1000003;
}
```

when I run compile command :

```
    python -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=. --proto_path=./third_party \
        --experimental_allow_proto3_optional \
        --error_format=gcc \
        --python_out=./py_interface/ --grpc_python_out=./py_interface/ common.proto
```

I got a raleted `common_pb2.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: api/pay_center/common/common.proto
"""Generated protocol buffer code."""
from google.protobuf.internal import enum_type_wrapper
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor.FileDescriptor(
  name='api/pay_center/common/common.proto',
  package='common',
  syntax='proto3',
  serialized_options=b'Z=git.domob-inc.cn/bluevision/bv_interface_go/pay_center/common',
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  serialized_pb=b'\n\"api/pay_center/common/common.proto\x12\x06\x63ommon\"j\n\x0e\x43lientTypeEnum\x12\x36\n\x0b\x63lient_type\x18\x01 \x01(\x0e\x32!.common.ClientTypeEnum.ClientType\" \n\nClientType\x12\x07\n\x03SMB\x10\x00\x12\t\n\x05\x42V_VL\x10\x01*\xcb\x01\n\x07\x45rrCode\x12\x1e\n\x1aPayCenterErrorCode_SUCCESS\x10\x00\x12)\n#PayCenterErrorCode_REQ_PARAMS_ERROR\x10\xc0\x84=\x12\x1f\n\x19PayCenterErrorCode__ERROR\x10\xc1\x84=\x12\'\n!PayCenterErrorCode__UNKNOWN_ERROR\x10\xc2\x84=\x12+\n%PayCenterErrorCode__ACCOUNT_NOT_EXIST\x10\xc3\x84=B?Z=git.domob-inc.cn/bluevision/bv_interface_go/pay_center/commonb\x06proto3'
)

_ERRCODE = _descriptor.EnumDescriptor(
  name='ErrCode',
  full_name='common.ErrCode',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  values=[
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='PayCenterErrorCode_SUCCESS', index=0, number=0,
      serialized_options=None,
      type=None,
      create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='PayCenterErrorCode_REQ_PARAMS_ERROR', index=1, number=1000000,
      serialized_options=None,
      type=None,
      create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='PayCenterErrorCode__ERROR', index=2, number=1000001,
      serialized_options=None,
      type=None,
      create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='PayCenterErrorCode__UNKNOWN_ERROR', index=3, number=1000002,
      serialized_options=None,
      type=None,
      create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='PayCenterErrorCode__ACCOUNT_NOT_EXIST', index=4, number=1000003,
      serialized_options=None,
      type=None,
      create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
  ],
  containing_type=None,
  serialized_options=None,
  serialized_start=155,
  serialized_end=358,
)
_sym_db.RegisterEnumDescriptor(_ERRCODE)

ErrCode = enum_type_wrapper.EnumTypeWrapper(_ERRCODE)
PayCenterErrorCode_SUCCESS = 0
PayCenterErrorCode_REQ_PARAMS_ERROR = 1000000
PayCenterErrorCode__ERROR = 1000001
PayCenterErrorCode__UNKNOWN_ERROR = 1000002
PayCenterErrorCode__ACCOUNT_NOT_EXIST = 1000003


_CLIENTTYPEENUM_CLIENTTYPE = _descriptor.EnumDescriptor(
  name='ClientType',
  full_name='common.ClientTypeEnum.ClientType',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  values=[
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='SMB', index=0, number=0,
      serialized_options=None,
      type=None,
      create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='BV_VL', index=1, number=1,
      serialized_options=None,
      type=None,
      create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
  ],
  containing_type=None,
  serialized_options=None,
  serialized_start=120,
  serialized_end=152,
)
_sym_db.RegisterEnumDescriptor(_CLIENTTYPEENUM_CLIENTTYPE)


_CLIENTTYPEENUM = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='ClientTypeEnum',
  full_name='common.ClientTypeEnum',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='client_type', full_name='common.ClientTypeEnum.client_type', index=0,
      number=1, type=14, cpp_type=8, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR,  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
    _CLIENTTYPEENUM_CLIENTTYPE,
  ],
  serialized_options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto3',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=46,
  serialized_end=152,
)

_CLIENTTYPEENUM.fields_by_name['client_type'].enum_type = _CLIENTTYPEENUM_CLIENTTYPE
_CLIENTTYPEENUM_CLIENTTYPE.containing_type = _CLIENTTYPEENUM
DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['ClientTypeEnum'] = _CLIENTTYPEENUM
DESCRIPTOR.enum_types_by_name['ErrCode'] = _ERRCODE
_sym_db.RegisterFileDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR)

ClientTypeEnum = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('ClientTypeEnum', (_message.Message,), {
  'DESCRIPTOR' : _CLIENTTYPEENUM,
  '__module__' : 'api.pay_center.common.common_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:common.ClientTypeEnum)
  })
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(ClientTypeEnum)


DESCRIPTOR._options = None
# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

My question is why there is no enum class in the Python type generated by compilation?
like

```
class ClientTypeEnum(proto.Message):

    class ClientType(proto.Enum):
        SMB = 0
        BV_VL = 1
```

I'm using `Python 3.9.17`  + `ibprotoc 3.17.3`

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc  
libprotoc 3.17.3
```